# Proper way to loop jQuery ajax and pass arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to solve once for all the problem of looping ajax request and passing 'index' into it (the problem below):

```
for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json[index]);
        }
    });
}
```

in this code within every 'success' callback 'index' will be 3. But I want to invoke callback with 0, 1, 2, 3. Many people are placing ajax request within a closure:

```
for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    (function(index){$.ajax({
        url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json[index]);
        }
    });
    })(index);
}
```

what in my opinion is a huge mistake - what if the request won't be there at the time? Than 'json' variable will be 'undefined'.

Does any of You guys have some proper way to solve this issue?

Comment: This is what you need http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: I dont get why you think closure is a bad solution here.

Comment: Beacouse it's invoking immediately and it's not waiting for the data respond.

Comment: @OskarSzura But the data is coming asynchronously.

Comment: @OskarSzura I don't think the `json` variable will be `undefined`, because the the `success` function in `$.ajax` is a callback and will be executed once the AJAX request succeeds, so you can be sure that `json` there is never undefined. So I think going with the closure is a good idea.

Comment: Maybe I've made some other mistake than... ok I'll try it again. Aslo I'll read more about this deffering. Thanks to all of You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the JSON will not be undefined.
If you would break the following code apart it would become more clear:

So instead of this:

```
for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    (function(index){$.ajax({
        url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json[index]);
        }
    });
    })(index);
}
```

...you can also write it like this:

```
function myFunction(index) {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {
                console.log(json[index]);
            }
    });
}

// and call it like this

for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    myFunction(index);
}
```

As you might already see, how are any of those two variables going to change by another call while they are defined inside the function?

(On a side note: I think it actually looks cleaner this way)